# Modeling the rate of change of choosing probability for a group

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Suppose $x\in[0,1]$ and $1-x$ are weight factors (or say choosing probabilities) of two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$.The rate of change of $x$ is proportional to the payoff difference of the two groups, say $P=\pi(G_1)-\pi(G_2)\in[-1,1]$. I tried with $\frac{dx}{dt}=kP$, but this does not restrict $x$ in $[0,1]$. Any idea regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the formula have restrict $x$, why can't you dust $define$ the domain?

Comment: Thanks, actually, I was expecting to find a better formulation that ensures the restriction.